# API last.fm как получить информацию о исполнителе с ласт фм

Tags: java, javafx, api, mp3

```
public void ArtistsWeb() {
        Caller.getInstance().setUserAgent("tst");
        Collection<Artist> info;
        String key = "d5caa39183e72b2d5d5f7f1b600c286b"; //this is the key 

used in the Last.fm API examples
            for(Mp3data data:mp3data) {
                info = Artist.getInfo(data.getArtist(), key).getSimilar();
                System.out.println(info);
            }

}
```

На выходе получаю нечто непонятное
[image: api]

Comment: То, как Вы выводите данные в System.out.println(info); Вам и отображается, а именно объект data с методом toString. Посмотрите внимательно, какие методы есть у класса Mp3data и воспользуйтесь ими.

Comment: Вы дайте ссылку на API хотя бы.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/l/Downloadlastfmbindings011jar.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам вот так работает

```
        public void ArtistsWeb() {
        Caller.getInstance().setUserAgent("tst");
        Artist info;
        String key = "d5caa39183e72b2d5d5f7f1b600c286b";
            for(Mp3data data:mp3data) {
                info = Artist.getInfo(data.getArtist(), key).getSimilar();
                System.out.Println(info.getWikiText());
            }
```